# as3 Math.random() cant seem to get it working correctly

Tags: actionscript-3

im working on as3 adobe flash, the FLA is a catching game and seems to work fine but i want to tweak it. i currently got :

trying to implement random speed per ball, i tried this:

```
var speed:Number = 7;
var RandomSpeed:Number = Math.random() * 7;
var ymov:Number =  RandomSpeed + speed;
```

and in the function i put this:

```
bgame[j].y += ymov;
```

(its [ j ] because i had to make another array to get the ball to drop)

its currently randomising all the balls in the game to the same speed but i want it to do it to individual balls.

there's also one more problem, when the game is finish (once player gets a score of 2 the game takes you back to home screen) the ball sprites that were on the screen and not caught still remain on the screen,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign different `ymov` speeds to each ball. As it is now you assign the value at the top level scope, then use it to update each ball's position. This is why they are all the same speed.

You can assign a new random `ymov` property to each ball in your `addBall()` function:

```
bgame[i].ymov = 7 + Math.random() * 7;
```

Then in your `Ballgame()` update function move the ball based on that property:

```
bgame[j].y += bgame[j].ymov;
```

BTW as a style note, classes usually are `UpperCase` while variables and functions are `lowerCase`.

Comment: thank you  it works :D, is there a way to make it so the speed wont be slower then 7 frames?

Comment: i still want it to be random, but not lower then 7 @Aaron

Comment: Sure, I edited my answer to use `7 + Math.random() * 7` -- this should give values from 7 to 14.

Comment: thank you soo much!!, have you downloaded the FLA? i would really really appreciate it if you could help with why the ball stays on the stage after the game over i asked my teacher today and he wasn't sure why

Comment: The reason the balls are staying on the stage when you return to the first scene is because those objects were added to the display list programatically. As such, you'll have to remove them programatically as well. Before returning to the home scene, iterate through your `bgame` array and remove the elements from the display list.

Comment: Exactly what @Marcela said. I was also going to suggest you remove the balls when they fall off the bottom of the screen: `if (balls[j].y > stage.stageHeight) { /* remove */ }`.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are only "rolling the dice" once and using that result for the speed of every ball. Make `ymov` into a function it will produce a different result every time. IE:

```
function ymov():Number
{
    var speed:Number = 7;
    var RandomSpeed:Number = Math.random() * 7;
    return RandomSpeed + speed;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick is there another way to do it?